# How to set the same viewmodel instance as the binding context for two views (pages) in Xamarin.Forms Shell?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin-forms-shell

I have a page and it's binding context is set to `SampleViewModel`. There I have a list of items (actually an ObservableCollection). Each of those items has an add to cart button. When clicked on that add to cart button,

1. I add that item to a new ObservableCollection as `CartItemsList`
2. I update a bool property `item.HasAddedToCart = true`.
3. And I increase `CartItemsCount` by 1.

Then after adding several items to the cart like that, I navigate to the Cart Page.
In the Cart Page. I need to show that `CartItemsList` and the `CartItemsCount`.

As my ViewModel (`SampleViewModel`) already has those `CartItemsList` and the `CartItemsCount` I thought setting the Cart page's binding context to the same viewmodel instance. But when I set the binding context in XAML it creates a new instant of that viewmodel.

It should be possible to delete cart items from Cart page. So if I remove a cart item from Cart page and if I go back to the main page, that change should be visible in the main page too. So maintaining a `CartItemsList` in the same viewmodel feels like the best approach.

But how to set the same vm instance as both those pages' binding context?

Comment: You can share the same VM instance between two pages, but not with XAML. you’ll have to set it in code

Comment: @Jason How can I do that exactly? The way I know is creating an object of the viewmodel and assign it to the binding context in Page's constructor. But that again is a new object, not the same instance.

Comment: pass the VM instance to the 2nd page on the constructor

Comment: @Jason I'm using Xamarin.Forms Shell. And I follow MVVM here. Therefore my navigation is happening from the viewmodel, not from the code behind of the page. In that case how can I do that?

Comment: @RuvindraYohan Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class for ViewModel so that you can call the same VM instance.

Here is the code:

```
public static class VMInstance
{
    private static SampleViewModel _sampleViewModel = new SampleViewModel();
    public static SampleViewModel SingleVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _sampleViewModel;
        } 
    } 
}
```

And then Pages.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VMInstance.SingleVM;
    }
}

public partial class CartPage : ContentPage
{
    public CartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VMInstance.SingleVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition, you can check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-7.0) about mvvm.